# Why is the "Through the loop" banner only on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, notification-bar, the-loop

When I happened to visit Stack Overflow today, I noticed a banner advertising the "Through the loop" survey:

[image: Screenshot of Stack Overflow]

However, I hadn't seen this banner on any other site on the network:

[image: Screenshot of Literature]

Is this [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)? Is "Through the loop" only meant for Stack Overflow and not the rest of the network? Does that mean that I shouldn't participate in it if I only use the other sites on the network?

Comment: From what I've gathered they're only focusing on SO because it's the most active site.

Comment: I get being in the loop or on the loop. What's the point of going through the loop?

Comment: @ScottHannen, to tie yourself in knots.

Comment: One of the "Through the Loop" questions asks how many years the respondent has been a coder, so there is definitely a Stack Overflow-centric feel to it.

Comment: The Through the Loop questionnaire is only relevant for the StackOverflow site.

Comment: @Alex How will that help Meta then?

Comment: @Alex Meta is as good as dead. SE is clearly looking to replace it. The Through the Loop questionnaire appears just to be a smoke screen and based on the associated blog post, SE won't hesitate to massage the outcome to fit their corporate message (graph only shows response of 80% of the survey population, the other 20% are mysteriously missing)

Comment: @Alex Soif they’re getting rid of Meta and the replacement is only for Stack Overflow, the rest of the network is... supposed to not give any feedback?

Comment: I think you are getting the point. Of course you can always provide feedback to /dev/null @Alex

Comment: @Alex so weird to see you talking to "yourself". ;-)

Comment: @ShadowThePrincessWizard You have to be careful now to make sure it’s actually me.

Answer (score 5):

Now that there are newer blog posts, the banner is gone and there's not even a link in the sidebar in the Community Bulletin of Stack Overflow.

Interesting to mention, on the other SE site it's still in the Community Bulletin.

My two cents: While "The Loop" is indeed relevant for all Stack Exchange sites (blog post being in their Bulletin proves it), it's also focused more on Stack Overflow which is mentioned by name many times in the blog post itself. Being the "flagship" site, that's where Stack Exchange the company invest most their time and resources, and they'll take all the people for the "councils" from Stack Overflow, not any other SE site. So naturally, non-SO users will find it less interesting to read, and for them the banner is just noise.

Comment: Its feel like if you are not a SO user, you are a second class SE citizen. Isn't it a kind of discrimination against minorities?

Comment: @aloisdg sure, many actions done by SE recently are technically discrimination against one group or another. And indeed, I won't be surprised at all if at some point the company will decide to close all sites except SOFU, and get back to the original trilogy. Or worse, close them all except SO. Those sites are a burden for SE, and they only lose money hosting them all, and having to support such a complex network of sites.